# positioning image in the middle of two divs - css

Tags: html, css, header

i have a little problem i am trying to position a image in between two divs but when i do `margin: 0 auto;` it does nothing so i do `display:block;` then it messes up my div to the right and my slider at the bottom.

[site messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfcTT.jpg)

when i remove `display:block` it does not mess it up the slider stays and the div does not go down, when i add it, it does what you see above.
so then i tried to float left but it fixs it but then it the image goes to the left.
so then i tryed margin-left: 50% then it goes to the right so i add display: block and it messes it up again. i read in some one elses post that they did `overflow:hidden;` but that did not work either.
here is my code:

html:

```
    <div id="siteheader">
            <!-- this is the first div that is to the left -->
            <div id="sitetitle" class="left">
                ...
            </div>
             <!-- this is the image i need in the middle -->
               <img id="headerlogo" src="http://barkitv.com/barki/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/new-logo-copy.png" height="40" width="40">

            <!-- this is the second div that is to the right -->
            <div class="signinmenu">
                <ul>...</ul></div>


            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
/* this class was applied to the div with the id of sitetitle */
.left {
float: left;
}

#siteheader > div.signinmenu {
    width: fit-content;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#siteheader {
    height: 85px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #8b4517;
}
```

to see it better and edit it better go to barkitv.com/barki

(I DID ALL OF THIS IN INSPECT ELEMENT SO I HAVE NO CODE)

The main problem is the `display:block;` when i add it to the image with the id of headerlogo it moves the signinmenu down from inside the header bar i want it to stay and also it moves the slider down.

Thank You

Comment: ok one minute @hungerstar

Comment: done i have fixed it at @hungerstar

Comment: I should have said, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With that we can help diagnose the problem and help offer a solution. Right now we only have a couple pieces of the puzzle. Unfortunately a screenshot is not as good as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hungerstar better?

Comment: No. Worse. Where is the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? A link to your site doesn't count.

Comment: read through it again i have explained better @hungerstar

Comment: No, no you haven't. **Again**, where is the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Nobody can replicate your slider, affected markup and your attempts with what you've posted.

Comment: can you tell me what part of my question you don't understand? @hungerstar

Comment: @hungerstar i have explained every thing

Comment: It's not about not understanding. It's about you not providing enough information for others to be able to diagnose the problem. We get that you're having a display issue. But there is no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (I'm blue, I'm a link, click and read)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! If you had provided a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example along with explaining things more clearly you'd likely have an answer or two by now. What you've provided is unlikely to get many, if any responses at all. You haven't even provided the relevant CSS.

Comment: is it better? @hungerstar

Comment: Somewhat, we'll see if it's enough. Thank you for posting the additional info/code.

Comment: can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your img in a div then position that div absolutely between your other two.

Adjust your HTML:

```
<div id="imgDiv">
    <img id="headerlogo" src="http://barkitv.com/barki/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/new-logo-copy.png" height="40" width="40">
</div>
```

Add to CSS:

```
#imgDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22.5px;
  left: calc(50vw - 20px);
  width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize my html formatting got killed. Take a look again...I fixed it now.